# adb shell remove directory with patenthesis windows

Tags: adb

I'm trying to delete a directory that contains parenthesis in its name. So far I've tried:

```
adb shell rm -r "sdcard/music/SomeArtist - (good stuff)"
```

And I get:

```
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

I'm on windows btw. Any suggestion? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the quotes are being interpreted twice: once by the Windows shell when it parses the `adb` command, and again by the Android shell. Remember that `adb shell foo` opens a shell on the device and runs the `foo` command there. When you run

```
adb shell rm -r "sdcard/music/SomeArtist - (good stuff)"
```

Windows is using the quotes to see the whole path as one argument, and then removes them. The command that actually gets sent to the device is then

```
rm -r sdcard/music/SomeArtist - (good stuff)
```

and the shell on the device interprets the `(` as a special shell expansion. There are two ways to avoid this. One way is to double the quotes, so that there's still a set left when the command gets to the device:

```
adb shell rm -r "\"sdcard/music/SomeArtist - (good stuff)\""
```

The second, and more generally useful, is to avoid trying to do everything at once. Use `adb shell` to open an interactive shell on the device, and then

```
rm -r "sdcard/music/SomeArtist - (good stuff)"
```

inside that shell to run the command you want. You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to exit the shell when you're done.

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to do it together with "su" yet in a batch file? I tried `adb shell "su -c rm -r -f THE_PATH"` but it didn't work as it complains about the "-r".